# How to create alternative mouse cursor for background app in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, winapi, mouseevent

We are using automation task to perform few object clicks in the background app on Windows 10, for this we use python code:

```
currentMousePos = win32api.GetCursorPos() # get cursor original location

win32api.SetCursorPos((650, 1200)) # background app requires cursor to be in this position, we temporarily set that position
win32gui.PostMessage(window, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, win32con.VK_RETURN, 0) # once the cursor is at the right coordinates that background app requires, we press `Enter` key.

win32api.SetCursorPos(currentMousePos ) # we promptly move the cursor back to original position, to help avoid disturbance
```

The idea here is that, our background application is constantly reading mouse coordinates, even when the background app is not the active window. Although, the above works - its not perfect and often you can see your mouse moving very quickly which is not great.

The main question here is, is it possible to create a secondary virtual cursor with fixed coordinates, from which the background app will read from? This seems like it would be a perfect solution, which means our main mouse cursor would not be affected at all.

If there are alternative solutions to this problem that anyone came up with, do post in the comments. The objective here is to isolate the main cursor from the background app, which allows you to browse your Web for example, while the background app is doing its work.

Comment: If you wish to automate a UI use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32). If you have a specific test scenario that requires changing the global mouse state, run it in a virtualization environment where you have full control over the mouse.

Comment: As far as your situation, clicking a few objects should be an exported API which can be called silently. Or at least use a reasonable way like @IInspectable suggested, when you don't have the background app source.